# How to store console output as a variable Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm having an issue storing the console output as a variable. I've created a short demo less than 20 lines of code when executed will output "hello how are you" to my node console, I'd like to store this text as a variable. Thank you

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null
    });
    const Page = await browser.newPage();
    await Page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
    await Page.on('console', code => console.log(code.text()));
    await Page.evaluate(_ => {
        var b = "123"
        console.log(b);
    });

})();
```

Comment: What's stopping you from assigning a variable inside the console event?

Comment: I get "undefined" error when I assign it a variable, can you show me a working example?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a promise, which will be resolved on the event, and then await for that.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null
});
let resolve;
var consoleLogPromise = new Promise(x => resolve = x);
const Page = await browser.newPage();
await Page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
await Page.on('console', code => resolve(code.text()));
await Page.evaluate(test);

var output = await consoleLogPromise;
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks hardkoded, but let's say our Page.evaluate contains an array, would using a promise still work in this situation?

Comment: You could make the evaluate return the value directly. `var output = await page.evaluate(() => return "hello");`